# Can you develop android apps without an intel processor?

Tags: android, intel, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to run the emulator on android studio but it won't emulate because I do not have intel x86 hardware acceleration installed. However, to install it, you must have an intel processor. My processor is AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 260. Is there any work around for this? I've enabled visualization technology and I don't have hyper-v installed either.

Comment: You can test on Android hardware. You can also test with the ARM emulator, but it will be very slow, particularly on larger screen sizes and with newer versions of Android.

Comment: If at all possible, don't use the Android emulator -- it's slow.  Plug a device in and test it on that -- that is fast.  If you value your time and if time is money, use an Android device.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) or an actual device.